# Laravel7 use function inside of a blade file

Tags: php, function, curl, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and have a view file that I put a function in the top of the view file.
However I am getting an error now on the page. I am basically just trying to create a page that queries a database of urls and then uses a curl function to see if the website is available or not.

```
syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) 
(View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/local-devcenter/resources/views/uptime-dashboard.blade.php)
```

Here is my code for the blade file

```
<?php
//stuck function here becauae needed it only in this template
function uptime_monitor($url) 
{
    $timeout = 10;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_respond = trim(strip_tags($http_respond));
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if (($http_code == "200") || ($http_code == "302")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // return $http_code;, possible too
        return false;
    }
      curl_close($ch);
}

?>
<table class="table-auto rounded text-center" id="sitegridtable">
                                <thead>
                                  <!--<tr>
                                    <th class="border w-1/4 px-4 py-2">Site URL</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">HTTPS</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">HTTP</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">Last updated On</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">Actions</th>
                                  </tr>-->
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($clientdomains as $clientdomain)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> {{$clientdomain->websiteurl}}</td>
                                            @if(@uptime_monitor('http://'.$clientdomain->websiteurl))

                                               <td>Up</td> 
                                           
                                            @else 
                                              <td>Down</td>
                                            
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td> </td>
                                            <td> 
                                                
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: You missed `@endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table class="table-auto rounded text-center" id="sitegridtable">
                                <thead>
                                  <!--<tr>
                                    <th class="border w-1/4 px-4 py-2">Site URL</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">HTTPS</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">HTTP</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">Last updated On</th>
                                    <th class="border w-1/6 px-4 py-2">Actions</th>
                                  </tr>-->
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($clientdomains as $clientdomain)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> {{$clientdomain->websiteurl}}</td>
                                            @if(@uptime_monitor('http://'.$clientdomain->websiteurl))

                                               <td>Up</td> 
                                           
                                            @else 
                                              <td>Down</td>
                                            @endif
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td> </td>
                                            <td> 
                                                
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
 </table>
```